# What's the monocle room's secret?

Tags: fez

The first world/area shows an "incomplete" room (white node) with many paintings, most prominently one of a monocled guy. What is the secret to this room?

[image: node screenshot]
[image: monocle plainting]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Look at the painting with many fezzes.** The hats are a code:

> **RT RT LT RT LT LT LT RT**

[image: lots of fezzes]

This anti-cube will auto-complete a QR code room later in the game. Vice versa, if you complete that QR code room, the monocle room will auto-complete (white node on map → gold).